# redirect with and without trailing slash to two different URL's

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have url with a trailing space that need to be directed to a URL. The same URL but without a trailing space needs to go to a different URL.

I've created a regular 301 redirect and works correctly for the first one but not for the second.

Redirect 301 /life/category/true-north-videos   https://example.com/2015/01/life-blogs-get-words/
Redirect 301 /life/category/true-north-videos/  https://example.com/blog/life/true-north

It redirects both, with or without trailing slash, to the same URL; the first one. Is it even possible to have two redirects to on with a trailing slash and one without?

Comment: The `Redirect` directive takes the given path as a _prefix_ - if you say `Redirect 301 /foo`, it means _all_ requests starting with `/foo` will be redirected - that includes `/foobar`, and also `/foo/`. Changing the order in which you put the two directives might already be enough here to fix the problem for this limited use case; if that doesn’t work, then you will have to use mod_rewrite and its RewriteRule directive instead to do this.

Comment: 04FS - You are a freaking genius! I just had to switch their positions and the redirects worked. Thank you so much!